# Error While creating PageObject Module in selenium For simple Tesng Testcase

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I tried to Create a Simple Program in Selenium Using PageObjectModel. While Running the Program it throws Null Pointer Exception. Don't Know what i am doing wrong.Is my initialization of Variable is Wrong. I know i am making mistake in initializing the By locator but don't know what i am doing wrong.

```
    public class main extends Base{

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5;
    private static final int POLLING = 100;

    protected WebDriverWait wait;
    protected static WebElement ele;
    protected By locator;

    public void Base() {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT, POLLING);
    }

    public WebElement waitForElementToAppear(By locator) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));//Line which Throws Null
        return ele;
    }

    protected void waitForElementToDisappear(By locator) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }

    protected void waitForTextToDisappear(By locator, String text) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(locator, text)));
    }
@Test()
   public void getURL() {
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            waitForElementToAppear(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Pom");// Line Which Throws Null.

}
```

And My Base Class Code where i have saved the properties of the driver.

```
 public class Base {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe"); // You can set this property elsewhere
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share error stack trace?

Comment: FAILED: getURL
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.demo.main.waitForElementToAppear(main.java:27)
 at com.demo.main.getURL(main.java:41)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)

Comment: Have you imported `ExpectedConditions`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the way in which you are initialising the `WebDriverWait` object.

Your WebDriver object will get instantiated only when the `@BeforeSuite` method runs in your `Base` class.

The logic of initialising the `WebDriverWait` is part of the method `public void Base()` in your `main` class.

But your `@Test` annotated `getURL()` method does not invoke `Base()` method. So your `wait` object is always null.

To fix this, invoke `Base()` within your `@Test` method or have your `Base()` method annotated with `@BeforeClass` annotation, so that it gets automatically called by TestNG.

Comment: This should nail the OP

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code

- Probably you do not need global variable declarations. Of course you can do it like that but make sure you initialize them.
- Do not put test methods in your page object
- ele will always be null
- Call the constructor

Probably you need something like following:

```
 public class MyPageObject extends Base{

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5;
    private static final int POLLING = 100;

    protected WebDriverWait wait;

    public void MyPageObject() {
        super();                                             //Call constructor of Base if needed
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT, POLLING);  //init wait
    }

    public WebElement waitForElementToAppear(By locator) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return driver.findElement(locator);                  //return WebElement
    }

    protected void waitForElementToDisappear(By locator) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }

    protected void waitForTextToDisappear(By locator, String text) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(locator, text)));
    }
}

public class MyTestClass {
   @Test()
   public void getURL() {
       MyPageObject myPageObject = new MyPageObject();       //Initialize your page object
       driver.get("https://www.google.com");
       myPageObject.waitForElementToAppear(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Pom");
}
```